# I failed to install ioncube on godaddy. Any advice?

Tags: ioncube

I got this message

```
    Site error: the file /home/content/xx/xxxxxxxx/html/admin/application/controllers/DashboardController.class.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation."
```

before and after installing ioncube. I think T've done installation correctly. I use Godaddy with PHP5.3

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install ionCube on your shared hosting account.  You can use the Wizard to do so.  http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

You will need to use the x86 and not the x86_64 versions of the ionCube loader.
Once you have this installed you will need to update your php5.ini file.  You will want to use the following format  in your php5.ini file:

```
zend_extension = /var/chroot/home/content/XX/XXXXXXX/html/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

The "xx" and "xxxxxxx" will be the same as are shown in your error.

After this change is made you will need to allow some time for the current PHP processes to die and restart before this change will register.

Answer (score 0):

`ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` needs to be installed by the server admin. Contact GoDaddy support.